# Remove sprite from arrayList when touched - "Invalid index 4, size is 4"

Tags: java, android, loops, sprite

Hi I'm trying to write a method that loops through an array list to check if the sprites in the array list have been touched and if so remove them. I've wrote this method but when I click the sprites, they stop and vibrate then the game crashes. Logcat provided below

**onTouchEvent**

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    /* Member (state) fields   */
    private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
    private Paint paint; //Reference a paint object 
    /** The drawable to use as the background of the animation canvas */
    private Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
    private Sprite sprite;
    int arraySize;
    private int hitCount;

    private ArrayList<Sprite> spritesArrayList;
    private GameView gameView;
    int numberofsprites = 5;
    int finalScore;
    private boolean gameOver;
    /* For the countdown timer */
    private long  startTime ;           //Timer to count down from
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;     //1 sec interval
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;  //Reference to class
    private boolean timerRunning = false;
    private String displayTime;         //To display time on the screen

    private Bitmap spritebmp;


    public GameView(Context context) {

        super(context);
        // Focus must be on GameView so that events can be handled.
        this.setFocusable(true);
        // For intercepting events on the surface.
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.background2);
        spritesArrayList= new ArrayList<Sprite>(numberofsprites);
    }



    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
        ResetGame();
        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this.getHolder(), this);
        gameLoopThread.running = true;
        gameLoopThread.start();

    }

    //To initialise/reset game
    private void ResetGame(){
        gameOver = false;
        hitCount = 0;
        /* Set paint details */
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
        paint.setTextSize(20);

        //Set timer
        startTime = 60;//Start at 10s to count down
        //Create new object - convert startTime to milliseconds
        countDownTimer=new MyCountDownTimer(startTime*1000,interval);
        countDownTimer.start();//Start it running
        timerRunning = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberofsprites; i++) 
        { 
        sprite = new Sprite(this);
        spritesArrayList.add(new Sprite(this)); 
        }   

    }


    //This class updates and manages the assets prior to drawing - called from the Thread
    public void update(){ 
        sprite = new Sprite(this);
        if (gameOver != true) { 
            for (int i = 0; i < numberofsprites; i++) 
            { 
            sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);
            sprite.update();
            }  
        } 
    }
    /**
     * To draw the game to the screen
     * This is called from Thread, so synchronisation can be done
     */

    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         Paint textPaint = new Paint();

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        //Draw all the objects on the canvas
        canvas.drawText("The Game ",5,25, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Score: " + hitCount, 5, 50, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Time: " +displayTime, 5, 75, paint);

         //Loop for sprite creation

         for (int i = 0; i < spritesArrayList.size(); i++) 
         {          
            sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);   
            sprite.draw(canvas);

         }




        if (gameOver == true)
        {
            canvas.drawText("Final Score: "+finalScore, 5,100, paint);
            int width = this.getMeasuredWidth()/2;
            int height = this.getMeasuredHeight()/2;
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            canvas.drawText("GAME OVER - PRESS BACK BUTTON TO RETURN", width, height, textPaint);
        }

    }
    public int getHitCount()
    {
        return hitCount;
    }
    //To be used if we need to find where screen was touched
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!gameOver)
        {
            Iterator<Sprite> i = spritesArrayList.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                sprite = i.next();   
                if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                        i.remove();
                       sprite = new Sprite(this);  
                       sprite.update();
                       hitCount++;         
                }

            }

        }

        return true;
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        gameLoopThread.running = false;

        // Shut down the game loop thread cleanly.
        boolean retry = true;
        while(retry) {
            try {
                gameLoopThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }
    private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

          public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
                super(startTime, interval);
          }
          public void onFinish() {
                displayTime = "Times Over!";
                finalScore = hitCount;
                gameOver = true;
                timerRunning = false;
                countDownTimer.cancel();
          }
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                displayTime = " " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;
          }
        }//End of MyCountDownTimer

      public void updateEasy()
        {
          this.gameView=gameView;
           numberofsprites = 20;

        }
        public void updateMedium()
        {
            this.gameView=gameView;
            numberofsprites = 15;   
        }
        public void updateHard()
        {
            this.gameView=gameView;
            numberofsprites = 5;
        }



}
```

**Logcat**

```
   05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639): Process: cct.mad.lab, PID: 1639
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639): java.lang.IllegalStateException
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.remove(ArrayList.java:589)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.onTouchEvent(GameView.java:166)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5655)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-06 14:36:41.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1639):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 14:36:41.633: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:41.633: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:41.633: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:41.633: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:41.633: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:41.703: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:41.703: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:41.703: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:41.713: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:41.713: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:41.763: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:41.763: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:41.763: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:41.783: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:41.783: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:41.823: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:41.823: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:41.823: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:41.823: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:41.823: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:41.863: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:41.863: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:41.873: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:41.873: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:41.873: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:41.903: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:41.903: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:41.903: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:41.903: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:41.913: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:41.933: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:41.933: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:41.933: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:41.933: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:41.943: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:41.953: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:41.953: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:41.953: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:41.953: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:41.953: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:41.963: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:41.963: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:41.963: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:41.973: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:41.973: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:41.993: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:41.993: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.023: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.023: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.043: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.063: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.063: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.073: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.073: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.073: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.073: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.083: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.083: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.083: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.083: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.113: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.113: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.113: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.113: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.123: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.143: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.143: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.143: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.143: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.153: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.193: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.243: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.243: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.243: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.253: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.253: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.263: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.263: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.263: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.263: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.323: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.323: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.333: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.333: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.333: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.523: D/dalvikvm(1639): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 618K, 66% free 4491K/13092K, paused 159ms, total 163ms
05-06 14:36:42.553: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.553: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.553: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.553: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.553: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.583: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.583: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.583: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.593: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.593: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.623: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.623: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.623: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.623: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.633: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.653: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.653: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.683: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.683: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.693: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.733: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.733: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.733: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.733: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.733: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.783: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.783: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.783: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.783: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.793: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.843: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.853: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.853: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.853: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.853: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.883: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.883: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.883: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.883: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.893: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:42.933: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:42.933: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:42.933: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:42.933: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:42.943: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:43.003: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:43.003: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:43.003: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:43.013: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:43.013: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:43.073: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:43.073: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:43.073: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:43.073: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:43.113: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:43.143: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:43.153: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:43.153: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:43.153: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:43.153: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:43.273: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:43.273: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:43.273: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:43.273: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:43.273: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:43.313: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:43.313: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:43.323: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:43.463: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
05-06 14:36:43.493: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:50)
05-06 14:36:43.493: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-06 14:36:43.503: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-06 14:36:43.503: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-06 14:36:43.503: W/System.err(1639):     at cct.mad.lab.GameView.update(GameView.java:106)
```

Comment: Well, you're not updating `numberofsprites` when you remove one. Is there any reason you're not just using `spritesArrayList.size()`, or better yet, an iterator? (Also note that currently you're skipping the sprite *after* the one you remove, which now has the same index as the one you've just removed...)

Comment: When you remove an item from the List, it shrinks by 1, so you're getting invalid index in `for` loop.

Comment: Side note: `gameOver != true` is equivalent to `!gameOver`, and the preferred way of writing.

Comment: What is an easy way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace these:

```
public void update(){ 
    sprite = new Sprite(this);
    if (gameOver != true) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofsprites; i++) 
        { 
        sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);
        sprite.update();
        }  
    } 
}
```

with

```
public void update(){ 
    sprite = new Sprite(this);
    if (gameOver != true) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < spritesArrayList.size(); i++) 
        { 
            sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);
            sprite.update();
        }  
    } 
}
```

and

```
        Iterator<Sprite> i = spritesArrayList.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            sprite = i.next();   
            if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                    i.remove();
                   sprite = new Sprite(this);  
                   sprite.update();
                   hitCount++;         
            }

        }
```

with

```
      for(int i = 0; i < spritesArrayList.size(); i++) {
            sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);
            if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                   spritesArrayList.remove(i--);
                   sprite = new Sprite(this);  
                   sprite.update();
                   hitCount++;         
            }

      }
```

This way, you will only manage objects that are actually within the array list.

Answer (score 2):

removing an element from the ArrayList is also changing the number of element in the ArrayList itself. You have an item less, but you are still looping on the list as it still has the same number of items. Use an iterator instead: E.g

```
Iterator<Sprite> i = spritesArrayList.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    sprite = i.next();   
    if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
           i.remove();    
           sprite = new Sprite(this);  
           hitCount++;         
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I used this method yet I still get the same problem. :/

Comment: the same  exception ?

Comment: Yes mate, 05-06 14:30:52.563: W/System.err(1539): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4

Comment: and is it always at GameView.java line: 156?

Comment: Actually the error changed- I've uploaded the log cat

Comment: `remove` throws `IllegalStateException` only if you haven't called `next()`. Check your code again

Comment: Hi, I've looked at the code but can't see what you mean? It's the same as the iterator code you provided.

Comment: could you edit your question **adding** the code you are using now and **without** removing the old one?

Comment: I've replaced the code with the entire class' code that I'm using now.